# pathlib Path `write_text` in append mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

Is there a shortcut for python `pathlib.Path` objects to `write_text()` in append mode?

The standard [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function has `mode="a"` to open a file for writing and appending to the file if that file exists, and a `Path`s [`.open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.open) function seems to have the same functionality (`my_path.open("a")`).

But what about the handy `.write_text('..')` shortcut, is there a way to use `pathlib` to open and append to a file with just doing the same things as with `open()`?

For clarity, I can do

```py
with my_path.open('a') as fp:
    fp.write('my text')
```

but is there another way?

`my_path.write_text('my text', mode='a')`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Not really, as you can see in the pathlib module exist 2 types of path classes:

- **pure path classes** {PurePath, PurePosixPath, PureWindowsPath}
- **concrete path classes** {Path, PosixPath, WindowsPath}.

Parameters of theses classes constructors will be just `*pathsegments`.

And if you look at the available read/write methods (read_text/read_bytes and write_text/write_bytes) you'll also see mode won't be available neither

So, as you've already discovered, the only way you can use mode with these pathlib classes is by using `open` method, ie:

```
with my_path.open("a") as f:
    f.write("...")
```

This is by design and that way the pathlib classes have become really "clean". Also, the above snippet is already canonical so it can't be simplified any further. You could use `open` method outside the context manager though:

```
f = my_path.open("a")
f.write("...")
```

Comment: I do not understand this statement: _This is by design and that way the pathlib classes have become really "clean"._ --- How does this make the classes _clean_? They already contain the `write_*` methods which are just not flexible enough. If the methods (or classes) are not _dirty_ how would e.g. adding an optional parameter `append=False` to them make them _dirty_?

Comment: @pabouk It's about protecting beginners... See discussions in https://bugs.python.org/issue46554

Answer (score 9):

There is no "append mode" for `write_text`, nor is there a corresponding `append_text` method. If you need it, you can write a function for it yourself pretty easily:

```py
def append_text(path, text, encoding=None, errors=None):
   with path.open("a", encoding=encoding, errors=errors) as f:
       f.write(text)
```

You might be wondering why such a thing isn't built directly into `pathlib` as a method. One reason is precisely because it is so easy to implement yourself that it's not really worth adding, but clearly that's not the whole story, because `read_text` and `write_text` would be similarly easy to implement yourself.

I think a major reason why `pathlib.Path` objects don't (and, indeed, shouldn't) have a `append_text` method is because it creates a hole for inexperienced users to fall into, which is a huge sin in API design.

Specifically, the hole I'm referring to is using `append_text` on the same file repeatedly in a loop. Because you're continually opening and closing the file, it is **slow**. Plus, doing so many unnecessary writes is probably not great for the health of your hard drive.

Worse, because the program will actually behave correctly (e.g. the file will have the contents they intended), they may not even notice anything is wrong, because they don't necessarily have a mental gauge on how long writing to a file "should" take.

This is exactly the sort of code a naïve programmer would write:

```py
from pathlib import Path

N = 100

path = Path("numbers.txt")

path.write_text(f"{N}\n")
for i in range(N):
    path.append_text(f"{i}\n")
```

Answer (score 6):

- Is it a nice solution? **No**
- Is it memory efficient? **No**
- Is it a one-liner? **Yes**

```
from pathlib import Path

my_path = Path('/shopping_list.txt')

my_str = '\nFresh Spinach\nFrozen Strawberries'

my_path.write_text(my_path.read_text() + my_str)
```

Comment: `my_str` doesn't have `write_text` method

Comment: well spotted @rok , thanks! **fixed** (context: I was previously referencing the wrong variable, see edit history)

Answer (score 4):

The `pathlib` methods `Path().write_text()` and `Path().write_bytes()` close the file connection on exit.

```
from pathlib import Path

Path('file.txt').write_text('my text')
Path('file1.txt').write_bytes(b'my text')
```

Using append mode i.e `open('a', ...)` will instanciate a `TextIOWrapper` which is also closed by  `write_text` / `write_bytes` on exit.

```
f = Path('file.txt')
f.open("a")
f.write_text('my text')
# or
f.write_bytes(b'my text')
```

Otherwise must close it manually

```
f = Path('file1.txt').open('a')
f.write('my text')
f.close()
```

but can be this way:

```
fp = Path('test.txt').open('a')
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='test.txt' mode='a' encoding='UTF-8'>
fp.write('my text')

fq = Path('test1.txt').open('ab', encoding='iso8859-1')
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='test1.txt' mode='a' encoding='iso8859-1'>
fq.write(b'my text')
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I've tried to read your first sentence slowly and carefully about five times, but I still can't make any sense of it. _.... the methods [...] close startment on finalize it_ ?!? All your base are belong to us ?!?

Comment: You can learn more about it at https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that "with/open" exposes just as big a "hole" for a naïve programmer as
having an append qualifier added to pathlib.

```
N = 100
for i in range(N):
    with my_path.open('a') as fp
        fp.write_text(f"{N}\n")
```

Comment: with blocks have to end with colon

Answer (score 1):

If its just too much trouble to use the WITH structure, this might provide a sort of work around:

```
from pathlib import Path as p
t1 = "The quick brown fox" 
t2 = "just jumped over the fence"
t3 = "to greet the lazy poodle."
mypath = p("D:\Try_this")
myfile = p("fox.txt")
if not(mypath.is_dir()):
    mypath.mkdir()
wholepath = p(mypath / myfile)
wholepath.write_text("\n".join([t1,t2,t3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function and bind to `pathlib.Path`

```py
from pathlib import PosixPath
from pathlib import Path as p

def _append_text(self:PosixPath, target:str) -> None:
    with self.open('a') as f:
        f.write(target)

p.append_text = _append_text
Path = p
```

Create a new path object

```py
sample_text = Path('/tmp/sample.txt')
```

Write mode

```py
sample_text.write_text('hello world')
```

Append mode

```py
sample_text.append_text('hello world, appended!')
```

Comment: IMHO, "binding" new function to built-in class will be confuse to people. If we go this route, I think it is clearer to inheritance from `Path` to add new method.